# Analytic Geometry Question

Tags: analytic-geometry

There is a point $M (2,1$) on a Cartesian coordinate system. There is also a point $P (x,y)$. What is the distance $MP$ in $x$ and $y$?

I can figure out that $ PM^2$ = $(x-2)^2 + (y-1)^2$, at least, I think so, but how to solve $PM$? I am not  the biggest fan of algebra so..

Comment: Take the square root...

Comment: I know that, but I don't exactly know how to or even if it is the correct answer.

Comment: that's right...

Comment: I know I have to take the square root guys, but I don't know what the answer is..

Comment: Well, the formula you have for the distance squared between $M$ and $P$ is correct. The formula for the distance involves taking the square root. Until you have specific value for $x,y$ you can't do much more...

Comment: You found the distance of (2,1) to any (x,y),understood?

Comment: What is the square root of the answer I found? That is my question really. I haven't done any algebra for a while so I forgot how to handle it. Is it just (x-2) + (y-1)?

Comment: $\sqrt{(x-2)^2 + (y-1)^2}$. That is the simplest form to write it in, and it is the correct answer.

Comment: How do I handle this: This answer, Root of (x-2)^2 + (y-1)^2 = Root of 2

Comment: If you are considering the Euclidean distance then the distance between $M$ and $P$ is exactly the one written above by Isaac.